# Failure creating output file: (OGR error: file location not a directory)

Tags: mmqgis

I am using the MMQGIS plugin to join sets of data on QGIS. I have been failing to do this for days on account of the output file location being rejected.
This error message appears:
Failure creating output file: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: C:\Users\cavca-admin\Documents\imd.shp is not a directory.)

It obviously suggests that I need to be choosing a directory as the output file location but I am unable to do this because it isn't valid. I have tried saving all relevant files in the one directory and choosing a range of file locations but nothing has worked.

Comment: It's a really bad error message from GDAL/OGR and actually means the file md.shp already exists and needs to be manually deleted before running the plugin again.

Comment: Message is bad in this context but if `md.shp` was a directory then GDAL/OGR would create the output shapefile inside that directory. Perhaps the message could be longer `...is not a directory where new layers could be added`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and what fixed it for me was exporting to `.geojson` format rather than `.shp`. I am not using `.shp` otherwise and am not subscribed to any ArcGIS services, so I figured there could be an incompatibility there. However, I cannot explain it technically.

`.shp` is a proprietary but open file format, so it should work for all of us.

But I am much happier with the [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) layers I have now.